# How to show progress bar with progress calculation in winform while filling dataset?

Tags: data-structures, progress-bar, winforms-interop

Here is my code i want to load a progress bar while dataset filling and data importing in a datagridview.Plz Help me

private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        string str="select Cert_ID,Card_Number,Name,DOB,Mobile,Gender,Relation ";
        str = str + " from dbo.beneficiary";



        SqlConnection conn = null;

        SqlDataAdapter sqlda = null;

        DataSet res = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            _connectionString = "xyz.........";
            conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(str, conn);

            sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

            sqlda.Fill(res);


            dataGridView1.DataSource=res.Tables[0];




        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }


    }
```